# ANGULAR. PRIMENG. ¿Puedo poner el botón Choose en la zona de content?

Tags: angular, typescript, fileupload, primeng

Estoy haciendo un componente para subir archivos con primeng:

https://primeng.org/fileupload

La cuestión es que el botón Choose (el que sirve para elegir el archivo que vamos a subir) se me queda en una zona llamada toolbar, y me gustaría ubicarlo en la zona de content (en esta zona podemos subir archivos mediante drag and drop).

Solo estoy usando el botón Choose, he ocultado otros botones como Cancel y Upload ya que he puesto la variable auto a true.

```
    <p-fileUpload
        mode="advanced"
        url="https://www.primefaces.org/cdn/api/upload.php"
        [auto]="true"
        [multiple]="false"
        accept="image/*"
        [chooseLabel]= "Buscar imagen"
        chooseIcon=""
        [showUploadButton]="false"
        [showCancelButton]="false"
        [maxFileSize]="maxFileSize"
        (onSelect)="selectImage($event)"
        (onRemove)="removeImage($event)">

        <ng-template pTemplate="content" >
            <ng-container *ngIf="uploadedFiles.length == 0">
                <p>Arrastre aquí su imagen</p>
            </ng-container>
        </ng-template>
    </p-fileUpload>
```

Gracias